# Not seeing my mac from google drive settings

Tags: mac, google-drive, google-drive-file-stream, google-photos

Re-install multiple times, granted full disk access to google drive. but not able to see my mac shows up in the left menu. any idea?

i am on mac 12.2.1, mac book pro (intel chip)

[image]

What I see from https://www.google.com/drive/download/

[image]

Comment: I don't think "your mac" is supposed to show up in the google drive preferences. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to "Set up Google Drive for desktop" from this instruction

https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop